# HttpResponseRedirect would't redirect edit page to another page that displays edit result by Django

Tags: django, redirect, edit

It only returns the edit page without being redirected to the the result page (title.html by entry function). Any help would be appreciated. My code is as below:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import util
import markdown2
import random
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django import forms

import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

class EntryForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

def edit(request, title):
    data = {
        'title': title, 
        'content': util.get_entry(title)
    }

    original_form = EntryForm(data)
    entries = util.list_entries()
    rand = random.choice(entries)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EntryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            content = form.cleaned_data['content']

            util.save_entry(title, content)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("entry", args=(title,)))
        
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
        "form": original_form,
        "random": rand
    })
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("create", views.create, name="create"),
    path("edit/<str:title>", views.edit, name="edit"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("<str:title>", views.entry, name="entry")
]
```

title.html for entry function:

```
{% block body %}
    
    {{ content|safe }}

      <form action="{% url 'edit' title %}">
            <input type="submit" value="Edit">
      </form>

{% endblock %}
```

I have changed the edit function, now the post method should work, I have tested it in my create a new page function, but the problem now is I can't get the initial data to display the form in order to edit it.

I used pbd to debug, the screen shot is as blow:

```
-> def edit(request, title):
(Pdb) print(title)
*** NameError: name 'title' is not defined
(Pdb) next

-> def create(request):
(Pdb) next
--Return--
> <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(219)_call_with_frames_removed()->None
(Pdb)
```

It actually worked before......and it should have the title variable as indicated in my html file. Please help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have `reverse('title', ...)`, but there aren't any paths with `name='title'` in your URL patterns. I think you want `reverse('entry', ...)`.

Comment: However I think you might have other problems as well. What is your code meant to do when `request.method == 'POST'` but the form isn't valid? Usually you would redisplay the form and show the errors. For debugging, you could add `else: print(form.errors)` to the view.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. It should be the name of the view instead of name of html. I know this, but somehow mixed the two since they've different name. Better use the same name for function and html next time. But after changing it, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try to use a debugger, or simply add `print()`s to your code to work out what's going on. For example, if `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('title', args=(title,)))` isn't running, then I would add `print(form.is_valid())` to confirm if the form is valid, and `print(form.errors)` if the form wasn't valid. And then if you realise that none of the code in `if request.method == "post":` is running, you could add `print(request.method)`, and notice that it should be `if request.method == 'POST':`.

Comment: It helped. Thanks a lot Alasdair! There is one more problem coming out. My edit page's post method works fine, as I have tried in my create new page function. But I couldn't get the original edit page with initial data displayed in order to edit it. It worked with the same code before. I have edited my post with debug result, using pdb.

Comment: Solved. I still need to do something if the form isn't valid. But for now, edit works. Code edited already.